# Простой ajax на select

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

Есть код

```js
(function() {
  const select_form = document.getElementById('auc-form');
  const model_select = document.getElementById('auc-model');

  document.addEventListener('change', function(e) {

    if (e.target.id == 'auc-make') {
      console.log(e.target.value)

      let url = '/getmodel/' + e.target.value;



      $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
        // let select_option_prev = document.getElementById('auc-model');
        // select_option_prev.remove(select_option_prev.selectedIndex);

        for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {


          let option = document.createElement('option');
          option.innerHTML = data[i];
          option.value = data[i];
          model_select.insertBefore(option, model_select.firstChild);
        }


      });

    }
  });
})();
```

Он делает простую вещь - загружает json и создает из этого список  для select. 
Код работает и всё в порядке, но он не удаляет предыдущие option
Подскажите как добавить удаление предыдущих option

Comment: $('Select').html('');

Comment: можете подсказать как этим пользоваться?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В начало обработчика ответа аякс добавьте очистку:

```
$(model_select).empty();
// или model_select.innerHTML = '';
// или while(model_select.options.length>0) model_select.remove(0);
```

Также измените вставку (поскольку firstChild теперь нет):

```
model_select.appendChild(option);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
model_select.options.length = 0;
```